# Reactjs Custom hook causing an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

can someone help explain why this code is causing an infinite loop and what is the best approach to fixing it please and thank you.

I am assuming its because of the useEffect within the App component which is causing a re-render which then the useState also causes a render therefore causing an infinite loop. I think I am not understanding how useEffect and useState works properly.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

interface IObject {
  isLoading: boolean;
  isError: boolean;
  data: any[] | any;
}

function useHook1(): IObject {
  console.log("hook 1 too many re-renders?");
  return { isLoading: false, isError: false, data: [] };
}

function useHook2(): IObject {
  const result = { isLoading: false, isError: false, data: "testing" };
  console.log("hook 2 too many re-renders?");
  return result;
}

export default function App() {
  const { isLoading, isError, data } = useHook1();
  const testResult = useHook2();
  const [state, setState] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("inside useEffect within App")
    setState(testResult.data)
  }, [testResult])

  console.log("too many re-renders?");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <p>{testing}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useHook2` returns a new object every time it runs. This means `testResult` is new/changed on every render, and your `useEffect` runs whenever `testResult` changes. So:

1. Your effect updates state, which causes a re-render.
2. On the rerender, `useHook2` gets invoked and `testResult` is updated.
3. `testResult` changed, so your effect runs again and you return to step 1, entering an infinite loop.

---

The solution, if I understand what you're trying to do, is to do the state management in the custom hook:

```js
function useHook1() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  return {
    isLoading,
    isError,
    data,
  };
}
```

You can simplify this a bit by collapsing the repeated `useState` usage into a single [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer):

```js
function useHook1() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    (state, action) => ({...state, ...action}),
    { isLoading: false, isError: false, data: [] }
  );

  return { ...state };
}
```

If you need to trigger updates from outside the hook you can make that available too:

```js
function useHook1() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    (state, action) => ({...state, ...action}),
    { isLoading: false, isError: false, data: [] }
  );

  return { ...state, dispatch };
}

export default function App () {
  const [{ isLoading, isError, data }, setState] = useHook1();
  
  return isLoading ? <div>Loading</div> : (
    <div onClick={() => dispatch({ data: ["new data"]})}>...</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: So based on what you said, i am going to assume that useHook1 is going to do exactly the same thing (cause an infinite loop) when I put the variable "data" that I destrcuted out of it in the dependency array within useEffect in app component. So how can i fix this issue? do i put the value in state in the custom hooks and return that state? i would assume this would cause the custom hook to render as well therefore still not resolving my issue. What do you think is a good way of attacking this issue? assuming that data can change in the custom hook

Comment: Updated answer with a possible solution. I'm in the middle of something right now but I'll try to come back and clarify a few things in a bit.

Comment: Updated with a couple clarifications.